# Duration of recorded file is longer than recording time using SoX?

Tags: linux, audio-recording, sox

I'm using SoX on Centos 7 to record the audio output from GQRX, a SDR application. I've selected Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo from the Recording Tab of the Pulseaudio Volume Control. I'm trying to save a .wav file with a sample rate of 6k. I'm using the command

sox -t pulseaudio 2 --rate 6k --channels 1 test.wav

This works and my test.wav is what I expect except that the duration of the file is about a third longer than the actual recording time. Recording for 3 hours and 15 minutes of time results in a file with a duration of 4 hours and 21 minutes.

I couldn't find anything online or in the SoX documentation concerning this. Is there something else I can try to make the wave the actual length of the recording?

Comment: So what's extra length? Silence? I don't see you specifying a duration for sox anyway?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Recording for 3 hours and 15 minutes produced a wav file with a duration of 4 hours and 21 minutes, 1 hour and 6 minutes longer than the recording time.

Comment: Not at all clearer. But perhaps it's because the default input rate of sox doesn't match with the pulse sink (source monitor) rate. Note that 6k is only the output rate of sox.